# A dense subgroup of a non-perfect group is itself not perfect.

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, proof-verification, topological-groups

Let $G$ be a topological group such that $G$ is not perfect, and $H$ be a dense subgroup of $G$. Is it always true that $H$ is not perfect?

Comment: Your proof is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the quotient map $q:G\to G\left/\right.[G,G]$, and let $A=q^{\leftarrow}(\{e\})$ be the pullback of the identity. Since $\{e\}$ is closed and $q$ is continuous, this implies that $A$ is also closed in $G$ (noting that $A\ne G$ by assumption). Since $[G,G]\subseteq A$, this means that $[H,H]\subseteq A$. Moreover, since $A$ is closed, $H\nsubseteq A$, so there exists some $a\in H$ such that $a\notin[H,H]$, hence $H$ is not perfect.